# jquery check if standard value is selected before submit in input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown box created with divs, but is it possible to check with jquery if other then the "Select Domain" is selected before submit, if not then it should not be submitted.

```
<div class="customselectbox" id="customselectbox_1">
            <input type="hidden" name="domainname" value="Select Domain" class="customselectbox_input">
            <div class="customselectbox_text" style="width: 82px;">Select Domain</div>
            <div class="customselectbox_array"></div>
            <div class="customselectbox_values" style="visibility: hidden; width: 122px;">
            <div class="customselectbox_valbox scroll-pane" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 122px;">

            <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 122px; height: 68px;"><div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 122px;"><ul>
                <li data-value="domain1.dk">domain1.dk</li><li data-value="domain2.dk">domain2.dk</li>              </ul></div></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I use this button for submit:

```
<button name="checkdomain" type="submit" id="checkdomain" value="Submit" class="btn btn-small btn-testemail">CHECK</button>
```

And this javascript to check another inputbox before submit:

```
<script>
$('#checkdomain').click(function (e) {
            var isValid = true;
            $('#name').each(function () {
                if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                    isValid = false;
                    $(this).css({
                        "border": "1px solid red",
                        "background": "#FFCECE"
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css({
                        "border": "",
                        "background": ""
                    });
                }
            });
            if (isValid == false)
                e.preventDefault();

            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jQuery line should get the text

```
$('#customselectbox_1 .customselectbox_text').html();
```

So i think it should be something like this p.s not tested

```
$('#checkdomain').click(function (e) {
            var isValid = true;
            $('#name').each(function () {
                if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                    isValid = false;
                    $(this).css({
                        "border": "1px solid red",
                        "background": "#FFCECE"
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css({
                        "border": "",
                        "background": ""
                    });
                }
            });

            if ($('#customselectbox_1 .customselectbox_text').html() == 'Select Domain') { isValid = false; }

            if (isValid == false)
                e.preventDefault();
                return false; 
            });
```